# Android 4.0.3 smartphone as a host for a computer

Tags: android, usb, host

Is it possible to connect an Android smartphone working a host to a computer (working as a device?) I am writing an app that is supposed to remote control a camera via smartphone. I have some trouble testing my app since emulators don't support usb connections. But when I connect my smartphone to the camera I can't really tell what goes wrong. I thought of connecting the phone to a computer so that it could e.g. display the characters it is receiving but I don't really know if it would work, as computers usually work as host to other devices, not the other way around.
Thanks a lot for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html

Altho as mention somewhere no google io mobile in android 3.1 didnt support host mode, maybe this has changed in 4.0 which might be true basing on this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQGxckZkH2g

Comment: The phone is able to work as host with android 4.0 - already checked. I am wondering how it is from the computer point of view - can the computer work as a device?

Comment: It needs to be device by default, and computer act as host by default. So I guess no, it cannot act as device out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

A computer cannot act as a Device. If you want to see what is happening on your smartphone when you connect your camera, use the 
   `adb shell`   `dmesg` commands to look at the logs and see if the camera is being detected.